# Предлоги "с" или "из"?

Tags: предлоги

Здравствуйте. Как правильно говорить: "вам виднее с Москвы" или "вам виднее из Москвы", если речь идет о косвенной видимости какого-то события человеком, проживающим в Москве. Например, тебе с (из) Москвы виднее, что случилось в Ницце.

Comment: Можно проще. Запомните: **извне** — кто-то или что-то внутри чего-то (помещение, территория и т.п.); **со стороны** — кто-то или что-то находится сверху или сбоку. Пример: достают ручку ИЗ пенала (изнутри); притащили рухлядь СО свалки (со стороны).

Answer (score 3):

Если человек живёт **в** Москве, то он находится "***в***нутри" неё и его взгляд во внешний мир направлен "***из***нутри", **из Москвы** ему что-то видно. Если в другом аспекте подобрать выражение "**на Москве**" (лежат обязанности по сбору налогов), то при направленности вовне в том же аспекте может получиться предлог "**с**" (**с Москвы** сняли часть обязанностей по сбору налогов) -  в вашем случае такое невозможно (человек не может находиться "**на** /городе/ Москве").

Answer (score 1):

В подобной конструкции, в родительном падеже, отвечающем на вопрос "откуда" со значением места (и/или движения), выбор предлога определяется предлогом для ответа на вопрос "где?" В/НА соответствует ИЗ/С.
*Живу на горе. - С горы скатилась лавина.  - Мне с горы видно все.

Живу в лесу. - Из леса вышел лось. - Мне из леса видно все.

Живу в Москве. - Из Москвы переехал в другой город. - Из Москвы видно все.

Живу на Урале. - С Урала переехал в Сибирь. - С Урала видно все.*

Дополнительная контекст, в частности информация о косвенной или прямой видимости, для выбора предлога здесь никакой роли не играет.

Неправомерное использование предлога (С в случаях, требующих предлога ИЗ), равно как и обратное - вероятное влияние украинского, в котором предлоги С и З (=русское ИЗ) неразличимы.

Замечу, что Alex_ander не совсем четко сформулировал эти вещи, подменив чисто фоормальное правило семантическим, причем не всегда соблюдаемом. В лесу, в Москве - это совсем не "внутри" леса или Москвы, да и суть не в этом.

Но совершенно правильно то, что при другой семантике управления "с чего" возможна замена ИЗ на С, но при этом соответствие ИЗ/С и В/НА сохраняется.

*На Москве лежат обязанности - На Москву возложили обязанности - С Москвы сняли обязанности.*

Здесь, как можно видеть, тот же родительный падеж отвечает на вопрос "С кого / с чего", а предложный - "на ком / на чем", но не связан с вопросами "где" и "откуда" .

Comment: Да, в украинском языке "из" и "С" - это одно и то же. Вариации "з", "із" и "зі" - просто фонетические, то есть для лучшего произношения и звучания. Но в украинском есть еще еще чередование начальных "і" с "й" и "у" с "в". Идея в том, чтобы было как можно меньше нагромождений согласных. Например, "він іде" (он идет), но "вона йде" (она идет), "Він увійшов" (Он вошел), но "Вона ввійшла" (Она вошла). Здесь "вв" произносится как действительно две "вв". Еще в украинском звонкие согласные на конце слова, приставок и перед глухими согласными не оглушаются. Произносится, как пишется: вавка (не вафка),

Comment: @YuryVovk Что я должен делать с этой инфорформацией?

Comment: А, простите, это модератор ваш ответ мне в комментарии перенес. Ну тогда ему виднее ))).