# Как правильно выбрать предлоги ИЗ и С?

Tags: общие-вопросы, вопрос

Как правильно: *из Москвы* или *с Москвы?*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предлог "из" или "с/со": информация из/со справочника](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457349/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

Правильно (в большинстве случаев): ***из Москвы***, например: ***приехать из Москвы, он родом из Москвы.***

Существуют пары предлогов, которые надо правильно употреблять:  В – ИЗ и НА – С,
Например:  поехать в Москву, на Урал – приехать из Москвы, с Урала.

Объяснение простое: Москва – город (предмет),  а Урал – территория (пространство).

Правильность употребления предлогов ИЗ и С на форуме обсуждалась неоднократно, например:

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457349/Предлог-из-или-с-со-информация-из-со-справочника](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457349/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/425163/Предлоги-с-или-из](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/425163/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7)

Эти предлоги могут  используются традиционно: *вошёл в театр — вышел из театра; был на концерте — пришёл с концерта.*

В некоторых случаях они взаимозаменяемы, в других же   выбор правильного  предлога **однозначен  и очень важен**, он показывает, настолько **вы владеете грамотной речью.** Чтобы это стало ясно в эмоциональном плане и хорошо запомнилось, я приведу пример из художественного романа:

*Стёпина мать была простой и скучной, как больничная каша на воде. И соображала плохо – почему-то решила, что Лара учится вместе со Стёпой в кулинарном колледже (он поступил туда сразу после девятого класса), и однажды спросила её громко при встрече:*

*– Ты ведь тоже с училища?*

*– Еще какая! – ответила злая Лара.*

(Лара – не очень успешная ученица элитной гимназии, но основы грамотной речи она там всё-таки освоила; знаний хватило на злую иронию.)

Comment: А я вообще не понял её ответа. Как-то он не согласуется с вопросом...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Такая себе игра слов (точнее, пробелов :)

Comment: Lol,  не могу не плюснуть.

Comment: ***Пробелов?***

Comment: Если вопрос сто раз повторяется, его надо закрывать, а не метать бисер перед "нагибаторами". А если уж отвечать, то полно. *"**С** Москвы сняли подозрения во вмешательстве в выборы".*

Comment: Я даю ссылку на другие ответы, в том числе на тот, где рассматривается ваша точка зрения (сняли с Москвы), так что при желании можно ознакомиться.  Что касается повтора вопроса, то об этом сложно судить. К примеру, у нас очень много вопросов про союз КАК, но в каждом случае нужен конкретный ответ. Если тему про предлоги ИЗ и С решительно закрыть, но, вероятно,  надо объединить все уже данные  ответы по этой теме  в один.

Comment: Sharon, объясните, пожалуйста. Я не понял.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  "Игра слов (точнее пробелов)":  – Ты ведь тоже **сучилища**?  – Еще какая [сучилища]!

Comment: Ааааа! Теперь понял, спасибо!))